# Rspec, Capybara and Poltergiest: Failed to reach server only when js: true is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have working integration/feature tests using Rails 4, rspec-rails 3.6, and capybara 2.18. I am trying to get these tests to pass on pages that are being rewritten in a javascript framework (React). To do so, I need to use a driver such as Poltergeist instead of the default headless browser so that javascript can run on the test pages.

I've installed poltergeist 1.18. I add `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist`, no problem. The tests pass with the old (html-only) pages.

However *just* adding `js: true` to an existing, working test (that is, before changing the rendered page to to the new version) and the test fails with

```
Request to 'http://account.example.com/user/sessions/new' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status
```

Note that this url is using the `account` subdomain in our application, and this may be related to the issue.

Here is one of the failing tests, isolated.

```
feature 'Vistor tries to login', js: true do
  scenario 'with valid login', :with_project_access_user do
    visit new_user_sessions_url
    fill_in 'user_session[login]', with: 'test@gmail.com'
    fill_in 'user_session[password]', with: 'mysweetpassword'
    click_button 'Log In'
    expect(current_url).to match('http://account\.')
  end
end
```

It's failing on the first line: `visit new_user_sessions_url`. This test passes if I remove `js" true`. In both cases, `new_user_sessions_url` is `"http://account.example.com/user/sessions/new"`

Using `new_user_sessions_path` instead of `new_user_sessions_url` doesn't work here because the subdomain is a required part of the route. If there is a way around the subdomain matching (without removing the subdomains -- they are used in our production app) that's a totally acceptable solution.

Since the test works without `js: true`, I have to assume that Capybara is doing something behind the scenes to handle the `example.com` domain. But how does adding `js: true` break this? And how can I fix this to get my existing tests to pass?

Comment: why don't you try with `visit new_user_sessions_path` instead?

Comment: Good question. Inherited tests and everyone insists on using `url` everywhere. However, with path, I get `No route matches [GET] "/user/sessions/new"`

Comment: So right, in this case when tests involve a login page redirecting to a page on a specific subdomain, how could `_path` work without the subdomain? Those paths will never match since the router isn't told what subdomain to use.

Answer (score 1):

When not using `js: true` Capybara is using the rack_test driver which completely ignores hostnames, so the only thing that matters is the path.  When you use `js: true` real hostnames are being used because the "browser" is querying them to figure out where to make its requests.  It is your responsibility to make sure whatever hostname your app is generating urls with resolves to an ip the app is listening on. Easiest solution for that is to add entries to /etc/hosts mapping the domain/subdomain names you're using for testing to 127.0.0.1.

Note: Poltergeist uses PhantomJS which is equivalent to an 8-9 year old browser at this point. This means you're most likely going to run into issues trying to run React apps on it, and you should really look into upgrading to a driver for modern browser - Selenium, Apparition, etc.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm using puma-dev and had previously tried setting `Capybara.app_host = "http://my_app_name.test"`. This looked like it worked, but it was actually querying my development application (`RAILS_ENV=="development")` instead of a version of the app running in the `"test"` environment. I'll look into the hosts thing later today but it seems like it would do the same, no? I'm not sure how to refer to a test-environment app server, since as far as I know that's sort of managed internally by some combination of rspec and capybara. Any insight?

Comment: (I actually considered it a benefit that phantonjs required me to find and install a bunch of missing polyfills :-) -- but thanks for the tip and I'll probably look for something newer soon)